# 02 manual civic clutch pedal adjustment

Tags: honda, clutch

Half a year ago I replaced the transmission and clutch of my 02 manual Honda Civic. I forgot to adjust the clutch pedal height.

The current engagement point on this new clutch is very high, meaning that the pedal does not have to be pressed down too far for the clutch to disengage. The clutch lines are hydraulic.

Before replacing, the clutch disengagement position was around 6 inches into the pedal press, close to the ground. With the new clutch, disengagement is after 3 inches, high up. Habit is to comfortably fully extend the leg down till the clutch pedal bottoms out. This means that there is an extra 5 in of pedal travel after clutch disengagement.

Q1: could this cause excessive wear to the pressure plate fingers?

This engagement distance is the same as the clutch pedal stroke in the attached image. It seems that this stroke cannot be adjusted with any nuts on the car. It is now a fixed distance of 3 inches even though specs say it should be at 5 in.

! [Service manual image]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWZDw.jpg)

Extra information:

The clutch pedal height was adjusted to near the height it was before clutch replacement. This was done by rotating the pushrod and In Step 2 e. Now this part is hard to describe. In order to get the pedal to the same engagement height as before, the pushrod length with shortened by screwing. The clutch pedal is held up by a spring. Before, there was no contact between the pushrod Cup and the part labeled stopper. Now that the push rod is shorter, the pushrod is pulling the spring supported pedal down, which applies Force to the part labeled stopper. If any of this makes sense, I don't think the system should work this way. I'm afraid that the push rod pulling on the master cylinder will cause the push rod to fail, where the couple eventually fall off the push rod keeping the clutch from disengaging.

I can't make this image up right on my phone.

[image: clutch pedal diagram 2]

Comment: I just replaced the clutch in my '03 Civic and have exactly the opposite problem: it completely engages by 2" off the floor. These are hydraulic clutches. There really isn't any adjustment a user can do on them (to my knowledge). You can ensure the clutch master is full of fluid as well as making sure it is completely bled.

Comment: @Paulster It will probably fix itself after a few hundred miles of driving, as the "high spots" wear off the brand new plates. This is similar to the way brand new brake pads feel a bit strange until the pads and disks wear down to the exact same profile

Comment: @alephzero - It already does have a bit better travel, but it's slow going. The clutch requires a 750 mile break-in period, of which I'm at about 10%. When the pressure plate and flywheel get heat soaked, it can be *really* hard to change gears, but so is the nature of the beast. This is a Stage 2 clutch, so I assumed it would be a little bit more difficult than an OEM one. No big deal.

Comment: Why would it be hard to change gears when the clutch is hot? Isn't there a big distance between the clutch ,flywheel and pressure plate regardless of temperature?

Comment: @paulster2 are you happy with the current engagement height of your clutch pedal right now?